# Convertir Objeto de claves numéricas a Array en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente Objeto:

```
let prueba = {a:'b', c: {0:{id:'pruebita'}, 1:{id:'otra mas'}}, d: {0: {name:'Luis'}}};
```

Las keys, ejemplo(0, 1), se integraran en un arreglo, como se muestra a continuación:

```
let resultado = {a:'b', c: [{id:'pruebita'}, {id:'otra mas'}], d: [{name:'Luis'}]};
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo poder realizarlo?

Comment: JSON != Objeto JS

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) para crear un nuevo `array`. Con [Object.Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) obtienes los keys de tu objeto.

```js
let prueba = {a:'b', c: {0:{id:'pruebita'}, 1:{id:'otra mas'}}, d: {0: {name:'Luis'}}};
let new_c = Object.keys(prueba.c).map(i => prueba.c[i]);
let new_d = Object.keys(prueba.d).map(i => prueba.d[i]);

//En el objeto prueba sigue estado c en su forma original
console.log(prueba.c);
//En new_c tenemos c guardado en un array
console.log(new_c);

//Lo mismo para d
console.log(prueba.d);
console.log(new_d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me han compartido una función recursiva para convertir los números en arreglo.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974698/10553253

Este es el código:

```
const demo = {a:'b', c:{0:{id:'one'},1:{id:'two'}}, d:{0:{country: {0:{name:'mx'},1:{name:'usa'}} }} };

const arrayfy = (o) => Object.entries(o)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if(typeof v === 'object') {
      const t = arrayfy(v);
      r[k] = '0' in v ? Object.values(t) : arrayfy(t);
    } else {
      r[k] = v;
    }

    return r;
  }, {});

const result = arrayfy(demo);

console.log(result);
```